# Calculating content size of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView` with a header on the top. In this header are other `UIViews`, `UITextViews` and `UILables` with dynamic heights

and I wondered, if there is a solution to calculate the content height of this header, so I can set its height in relation to its content. I know I could calculate it manually but sometimes such a function could be comfortable.

**With Auto-Layout:**

You can use this tutorial http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   sizeHeaderToFit()
}

func sizeHeaderToFit() {
   let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!

   headerView.setNeedsLayout()
   headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

   let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
   var frame = headerView.frame
   frame.size.height = height
   headerView.frame = frame

   tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Comment: If you are using Auto Layout this would be the way to go http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah thanks it worked! :) @riik

Comment: I have used the same solution, But my headerview is overlapping with table view cells. Do you have any idea why? Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**With Auto-Layout:**

You can use this tutorial http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   sizeHeaderToFit()
}

func sizeHeaderToFit() {
   let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!

   headerView.setNeedsLayout()
   headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

   let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
   var frame = headerView.frame
   frame.size.height = height
   headerView.frame = frame

   tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```